# Use Google Photos from within Camera app on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: photos, camera

Is it possible to make the default camera app on the Galaxy S7 use Google Photos instead of Samsung Gallery?

I like the preinstalled camera app, but pressing the thumbnail icon in the interface will always open the Samsung Gallery, even though I have set Google Photos as the default app for photo viewing.

For newer devices, creating an "app shortcut" has been recommended in various articles and discussion forums (e.g. at [lifehacker.com](https://lifehacker.com/get-a-quick-shortcut-to-google-photos-from-your-camera-1789254932)). This however doesn't seem to be available on the Galaxy S7.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the gallery is hardcoded in the camera app of your device. 
There's no way you can change it. Atleast not for now. Maybe in later updates, they'd make it available.